# Is “If I would have X” an Indian shibboleth?

Tags: subcontinental-english, shibboleth

As I was reading [a deleted question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17457/is-this-sentence-correct-or-not) that asks whether

> If I would have sweet dreams, they would be about you. If my dreams ever come true, it will be with you.

is correct, I noticed that the incorrect use of “if I would have” in the first sentence somehow made me feel like the poster was Indian. I don't know exactly why, but it felt like something my former Indian colleagues could have said. So, is this particular error typical of (or quite likely to be made by) Indians, or is it just some weird feeling I'm getting for no reason?

Comment: Most (all?) of the people I've heard use it are native en-us speakers.

Comment: Native en-us speakers certainly *can* say "If I would have", but the example that F'x linked sounds wrong to me. I would have said just "If I had" in that sentence.

Comment: It's not a common usage in India (in fact I've never heard it before) - so most likely your former colleague picked it up somewhere else.

Comment: Whenever I see the phrase "if I would have", I always think it is because the reader is expanding "if I'd have" wrongly, instead of expanding to "if I had have".

Comment: I think user653 is spot on with the reason why people make this (to me, at least) particularly irritating error. But it's certainly not peculiar to Indians - I've heard linguistically-challenged native speakers come out with it here in the UK.

Comment: @user663. What do you mean when you say "instead of expanding to If I Had Have"? When can such a sentence be used? It sounds very ungrammatical to me.

Comment: I've definitely heard "if I had have (+past participle)", as a colloquial alternative to "if I had (+past participle)". I've never heard "if I would have", except by non-native speakers. It sounds completely wrong to me (in contexts like this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dutchmen sometimes make the same mistake, because the construction * *he would do x, if y **would be** true* is correct in Dutch, besides *he would do x, if y **were** true*, which is also correct in Dutch. This might apply to some other European languages as well.

In addition, I recently read that some English style guides warn(ed) against this usage too, which makes one wonder whether it is or was not more widely used, perhaps mainly in certain non-standard dialects.

Comment: I have most-commonly heard India-native speakers use the construction "If I would have [object]" **not** "If I would have [verb]"

Comment: @NewAlexandria: How about with other verbs?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @NewAlexandria: If she'd be my daughter, I would punish her.

Comment: It's not the pattern I observe.  Rather: "If I would have punishment for her..."

Comment: @NewAlexandria: Okay, so you suggest that it is only/mainly Indian with "have"? That could be, I don't know; but it could be Dutch etc. with *any* verb, so...it would be a complicated phenomenon, in that case.

Comment: Maybe; I'll listen more for the use of any verb, and whether *'if'* is an important part of the construction, as *"If..... would [object/verb]"*

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. This is pretty common when expressing regret towards your past self:

> If only I would have known!
>
> If only I would have taken the bus instead of the tram...
>
> If I would have said, "I love you," she would not have left me.

Comment: If only I had known! — If I had said that, she would not have left me.

Comment: As discussed in the question linked above, all three of these examples would be regarded by many as incorrect.

Comment: @F'x: Oh, sure, your usage is probably more correct. I was simply trying to say that I hear this phrasing all the time and don't know _anyone_ from India (or did you mean Native Americans?) It is usually pronounced via contractions: "If only I would've known!" My hunch is that the "would" seems to be rooted in a jump from "I would have said" instead of "I had said." You can simply say, "Had I said..." but it gets troublesome saying, "Would I have said..." so people say "If I would have said..." I dunno. Just guessing at this point. But I _do_ hear people say that.

Comment: @Steve: I agree. My point was not correctness. It was answering the question: "Is this an Indian shibboleth?" My answer is, "Probably not. I hear this quite often as such."

Comment: Ah, fair enough then!

Comment: @MrHen I don't think this is a good answer because you have changed the constructed form in different ways, and as such have gone astray from the subtleties of a *shibboleth*

Answer (score 0):

This thread is about the subjunctive case. There's a quick explanation on this page:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-the-subjunctive-mood-in-english.html

In short, don't use "would" in the clause with "if". Many people do, but it is not considered grammatically correct.

NOT - "If I would have known..." but rather "If I had known, I would have..."
NOT - "If she would have said that..." but rather "If she had said that, he would have..."
NOT - "If you would have paid..." but rather "If you had paid, we might have gotten a better answer.

Comment: It's ok, but I think you would need to provide context to how a given culture developed this subjunctive misunderstanding based upon their native language structure.